# installing vagrant-librarian-chef plugin

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, vagrant-plugin, chef-zero

I'm trying to install the vagrant librarian plugin with this command:

> vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-chef

But I keep getting this error message:

> chef-zero requires Ruby version >= 2.3.1.

So I've uninstalled chef-zero and downloaded and then set my Ruby version to 2.3.1 but I continue to get the same error message.

I've reset the terminal but still the same error.

Comment: could you solve the issue? tnx

Comment: @Delavega I couldn't solve it so I switched to Ansible.